# How to make Django select box option not selectable?

Tags: python, django

I have made a Django Form using Django Crispy Forms. I used the Foreign Key concept to display dropdowns in my page. I would like the first option of the dropdown ('Choose..') to be shown to the user but he/she must not be able to select it. 
It is very easy to do with JavaScript but I'm not sure how to do it with Django.

[My page with the dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJnov.jpg)

I am also attaching the code for my forms.py and models.py.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Organization(models.Model):
    orgname = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.orgname)

class Team(models.Model):
    teamID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    teamName = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teamName)

class AgileTeam(models.Model):
    agileTeamID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    agileTeamName = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.agileTeamName)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    assoc_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agile_team = models.ForeignKey(AgileTeam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Organization, Team, AgileTeam, Employee

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value = True))
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name', 'assoc_id', 'username', 'password', 'organization', 'team', 'agile_team',)
        labels = {
            'name':'Name',
            'assoc_id':'Associate ID',
            'username': 'Username',
            'password': 'Password',
            'organization':'Organization Name',
            'team': 'Team Name',
            'agile_team': 'Agile Team'      
        }

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(EmployeeForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Code to make fields optional and to set the first option of dropdown as "Choose.."
            self.fields['organization'].required = False
            self.fields['organization'].empty_label = "Choose.."
            self.fields['team'].required = False
            self.fields['team'].empty_label = "Choose.."
            self.fields['agile_team'].required = False
            self.fields['agile_team'].empty_label = "Choose.."
```

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I hope I have been able to explain my problem properly.

Thanks in advance!
May the force be with you.

Comment: Did you try keeping the required attribute of organization, agile_team and team as True

Comment: How does that matter?
I just need the option of "Choose.." to be displayed but not clickable

Yes, I did try it. But it does not change anything.

Comment: You mean you don't want value choose  to be submitted?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. The user should be able to see the "Choose.." option, but not select it.
Is there a way to disable that specific option in Django forms?